# Address of array provided as std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

I'm trying to construct a ROM, which has as declaration `a : in std_logic_vector(5 downto 0)` for the access address. My problem its that I don't know how to access the ROM array with a std_logic_vector, Should I use a cast to integer or what else  can I do?

My code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
entity imem is
    GENERIC(CONSTANT N : INTEGER := 32);
    port (a : in std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
         result : out std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0));
end imem;


architecture behavior of imem is
    signal addres : integer;
    type memory is array (0 to 64) of std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0) ;
    constant myrom : memory := (
         2 => x"11111111" , --255
         3 => x"11010101" , 
         4 => x"01101000" , 
         6 => x"10011011" , 
         8 => x"01101101" , 
         9 => x"00110111" , 
         others => x"00000000" ) ;

begin 
    addres <= signed(a);
    result <= memory(addres);

end behavior;
```

With this code as shown I get the following error:

```
imem.vhd:25:21: can't match type conversion with type integer  
imem.vhd:25:21: (location of type conversion)
imem.vhd:26:21: conversion not allowed between not closely related types  
imem.vhd:26:21: can't match type conversion with type array type "std_logic_vector"
imem.vhd:26:21: (location of type conversion)
ghdl: compilation error
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `a` is an unsigned address value, then you must first cast it to unsigned, and then to integer.  Note that the `result` should access `myrom` and not `memory` type.  The code can then be:

```
addres <= to_integer(unsigned(a));
result <= myrom(addres);
```

And you can even skip the intermediate `addres` signal and do:

```
result <= myrom(to_integer(unsigned(a)));
```

The `memory` type is also one longer than required, since the 6-bit `a` input can only cover 0 .. 63, and not 0 .. 64.  A better way to declare the `memory` type would be through use the the `'length` attribute for `a`, like:

```
type memory is array (0 to 2 ** a'length - 1) of std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
```

Comment: With VHDL-2008 package numeric_std_unsigned, this becomes:
result <= myrom(to_integer(a)) ; 
Keep in mind, that this may not yet be synthesizable, however, do try it out and file a bug report against it if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

**ghdl semantics are by default strict -1993 which has an impact on Morten's answer's changes**

For:

```
type memory is array (0 to 2 ** a'length - 1) of 
        std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
```

we get:

> ghdl -a imem.vhdl
> imem.vhdl:15:29:warning: universal integer bound must be numeric literal or attribute

Tristan Gingold the author of **ghdl** authored an Issue Report leading to a Language Change Specification in 2006, which gave explicit permission to then current (-2002) implementations to treat a range with an expression as one bound as convertible to an integer range when the other bound is a universal integer (a literal).  The LCS didn't give permission to do the conversion in implementations conforming to earlier versions of the standard. Tristan's **ghdl** is strictly by the book here and by default is -1993 compliant and generates an error.

There are two ways to deal with the error.  Either use the command line option to **ghdl** during analysis to specify a version of the standard where the range can be converted to type integer or provide the range directly.

From ghdl --help-options we see:

> --std=87/93/00/02/08  select vhdl 87/93/00/02/08 standard

Where this command line flag can be passed as in ghdl -a --std=02 imem.vhdl.

Also the range type can be declared directly as in:

```
type memory is array (natural range 0 to 2 ** a'length - 1) of 
            std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
```

Both methods of analyzing type memory work.

And the moral of all this is that VHDL is a tightly typed language.

Notes

---

1. -2008 compliance is not fully implemented in current versions of **ghdl**.)
2. There's historical support for interpreting the standard to support the conversion anyway. The LCS overcomes ambiguity.
3. See IEEE Std 1076-1993 3.2.1.1 Index constraints and discrete ranges para 2 and IEEE Std-1076-2008 5.3.2.2 Index constraints and discrete ranges para 2.

---

4. Tristan has since changed the `--std=` options eliminating -2000 compliance as well as the default standard **to 93c** which introduces a set of standard relaxations to more closely match industry practices of  VHDL tool vendors. The user of a more recent version of ghdl can use  `--std=93` for strict standard compliance. The issue originally hinged on the VASG (VHDL Analysis and Standardization Group) sponsored by DAC not being allowed to issued Interpretations of standards after -1987. It's safe to say there is no single implementation of any VHDL standard that completely adheres to a particular revision.